# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python'

Tags: tensorflow

Exact command to reproduce: toco --help

I am trying to run the codelab tutorial of tensorflow lite. After installing tf-nightly, when I try to run the command "toco --help", I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python'.

I have tried this on 3 computers( all Windows) and the same problem persists.

Source code / logs

C:\Users\HP\Downloads>toco --help

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main "main", mod_spec)
>
> File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in run_code
>   exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\toco.exe_main.py", line 5, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python'

Comment: Have you found a workaround eventually?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and apparently TOCO doesn't work on Windows machines, 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16374

My alternative to optimize the model was to user TensorFlow Mobile, instead of TensorFlow Lite, and use 'optimize_for_inference'. You could also try on a linux environment.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by downgrading tensorflow to 1.7

```
pip install --upgrade "tensorflow==1.7.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved
Clone the tensorflow repository an copy the lite folder from tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib
and paste it in the C:\Users\$USERNAME$\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite

Comment: Tried this. New error 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python.toco_wrapper'

Comment: did you try installing toco via **pip install toco**

Comment: @AmythPaddy this command will install a completely different toco... I have tried your method but it gives me the same error as for OP.

Comment: @pblead26 Thanks, so weird that there is no implementation on Windows, going to run it on Linux then..

Answer (score 0):

The tensorflow library in Python36 has some missing files. My Python36 folder is in c:\Python36. So the toco will load "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\python". Whoever coded the toco forgot to copy the whole folder into there.
[image: Cripple lite folder]

You need to copy from your tensorflow folder to the lite folder. My tensorflow is at
"c:\tensorflow". The lite folder looks like this:
[image: full lite folder]

Copy all files from "C:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\lite\python" to "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\python".
[image]

Now, you need to make a test, "toco --help"
[image]